# D3.js - Cannot read property 'axis' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my code snippet:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH -  MARGINS.right]).domain([scaleMin, scaleMax]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([minValue,maxValue+numberOfSignals*300]);
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);
```

this is my code. But everytime i run it i get the error "plot:91 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'axis' of undefined".
The thing is that it worked before. was there an update?
Thanks!

Comment: which version of d3 are you using?

Comment: the newest one - 4.1.1

Comment: use version 3 it will work..the APIs you are using is for version 3.

Comment: The problem is that you are using a mix of things.
This line will work in d3 v4 `xScale = d3.scaleLinear()`
This line will work on on d3 v3 `d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)` so I ll suggest please choose your version correctly.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

For version 4
It has to be:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([scaleMin, scaleMax]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([minValue,maxValue+numberOfSignals*300]);


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale);
```

Instead of this code below(will work in version 3):

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");
```

Comment: Hey, Cyril, I was editing the question to add the d3v4 tag and I just realised that there are two of them... do you have enough RP to make them synonyms?

Comment: Nopes @GerardoFurtado I don't have the RP to do it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado  I am only aware of the d3v4. What other tag have you seen?

Comment: There is one named `d3.js-v4`, with only two questions tagged.

Comment: works for me when I move from v3 to v5 fine! Thanks!